# threading method in imageprocessing PyQt application

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I develop a program which is constantly "watching" a specific folder, and when some image is copied into that folder, a function is called from another class and start the processing. The problem that these images are huge so whenever that image processing function starts, the ui freezes until the end of the process. I learnt that QThread might be the solution, but I cannot figure it out how to apply when I have many function in the class...

To be more specific, please, see the order of the steps.

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__():

    functions = Functions()
    ...
    self.something.signal.connect(self.functions.doStuff)

class Functions(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__():

    imProc = ImageProcessing() 

    def doStuff():
        initialImage = loadimage(...)
        processedImage = imProc.process1(initialImage)

class ImageProcessing(QtCore.QObject) 
    def __init__(): 

    def process1(original_image):
        do maximum likelihood on the image
        return segmented image

    def process2(original_image):

        do another image processing task
        return segmented image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    main.exec_()
```

The problem is when process1() is running the main window freezes...could you please advise how to run the process1() in the background separately from the ui?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This cannot be answered in a thread safe way without knowing the contents of the method you want to run in the thread.

Comment: @three_pineapples I'd like to run the function1() containing the maximum likelihood segmentation method on a separate thread and return the segmented image. What do you think, is it possible?

Comment: @three_pineapples What i cannot figure out how to run the process1(image) function on the way that it does not freezes the main ui. I do not have to display anything on the ui, so basicely I do not need to signal any value (or I am wrong?). The function return an image which is then saved into the folder from where the original_image is copied. Do I have to detail the maximum likelihood algorithm? Or what info do you need? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out. I give a generic description how I solved it:

First here is my ImageProcessing class...

```
class ImageProcess(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        #machine learning algorithm, which results a processed image...
        self.emit( QtCore.SIGNAL('image'), processedImage) 
        return
```

The I have my Functions class...

```
class Functions(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__():

        self.improc = ImageProcess()
        self.connect(self.improc, SIGNAL("image"), self.processImage)

        self.segmented_image = []

        self.improc.setPath(self.image)
        self.improc.start()

    def processImage(self,seg_img):    
        self.segmented_image = seg_img
```

and then QMainWindow is set up as usual...

Hope it helps for somenone who is srtuggeling with Qthread, signal-slots application...